# Recycler View not showing results in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement recycler view inside some of my fragments, and i tried to do so on the first one. No issues are displayed in the IDE on compilation time, but on runtime I get this message on the console: `E/RecyclerView: No layout manager attached; skipping layout`. Also, data is not showing in my application.

Here is my Fragment:

```
    var sandwiches = listOf<Sandwich>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentSandwichesBinding>(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_sandwiches, container, false
        )

        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
        val dataSource = NbaCafeDB.getInstance(application).sandwichDao
        val viewModelFactory = SandwichViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)

        val sandwichViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(SandwichViewModel::class.java)

        sandwiches = sandwichViewModel.getAll()

        val adapter = SandwichAdapter(sandwiches)
        binding.sandwichRecycler.adapter = adapter

        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

And here is my Adapter:

```
class SandwichAdapter (val sandwich: List<Sandwich>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SandwichAdapter.SandwichHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount() = sandwich.size

    class SandwichHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        fun bind(sandwich: Sandwich) {
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sandwichNom).text = sandwich.nomSandwich
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sandwichDesc).text = sandwich.descSandwich
            view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sandwichPreu).text = (sandwich.preuSandwich.toString()+" €")
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): SandwichHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val view = layoutInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.sandwich_cell_layout, parent, false)

                return SandwichHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SandwichHolder {
        return SandwichHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SandwichHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(sandwich[position])
    }

}
```

Also, I'm retrieving data from a room database and using viewModel and viewModelFactory, in case that changes anything.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to set `LayoutManager` to RV like this:
`binding.sandwichRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)`.

Just add `app:layoutManager` to `RecyclerView` in your xml.

The default orientation of `LinearLayoutManager` is `VERTICAL`, but if you want to change orientation as `HORIZONTAL`, you can just add `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical|horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```